# Searchkick search data working in test but not in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am experiencing some weird behavior with the Elasticsearch wrapper Ruby gem [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), and I'd love your help!

### The Issue

The expected behavior is that I should be able to search for a full name with a space in it. This works in my test, but not in browser.

### The Code

#### account.rb

```
class Account
  searchkick word_start: [
    :first_name,
    :last_name,
    :name, # <======================== key line
    :email,
    :phone,
    :company,
  ], callbacks: :async

  def self.index_search(query:)
    search(
      query || '*',
      fields: [
        :first_name,
        :last_name,
        :name, # <======================== key line
        :email,
        :phone,
        :company,
      ],
      match: :word_start,
      where: { test_account: false },
      order: { created_at: :desc },
      limit: 20,
      misspellings: false,
    )
  end

  def search_data
    {
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      name: "#{first_name} #{last_name}", # <======================== key line
      created_at: created_at,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      test_account: test_account,
      company: company
    }
  end
end
```

#### account_test.rb - ALL OF THESE PASS

```
class AccountTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  describe "::index_search" do
    let(:account_0) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:account, company: "Xyz Consulting")  # name: "Testy McTesterson"
    end
    let(:account_1) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:account, first_name: "Bob") # name: "Bob McTesterson"
    end
    let(:search) do
      Account.index_search(query: query)
    end

    before :all do
      account_0 and account_1 # instantiate
      Searchkick.disable_callbacks
      Account.reindex
    end

    describe "when there are spaces in the string" do
      let(:query) { "xyz con" }

      it "finds all and only the appropriate records" do
        assert_equal [account_0.id], search.map(&:id)
      end
    end

    describe "when the query matches the full name" do
      let(:query) { "bob mct" }

      it "finds all and only the appropriate records" do
        assert_equal [account_1.id], search.map(&:id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Note:** when I comment out the three 'key lines' from  `account.rb`, the second of those tests fails. So the `name:` in the `#search_data` method seems to be working.

#### search_controller.rb (essentially)

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts "params[:query]: #{params[:query]}"
    puts "custom_search.map(&:first_name): #{custom_search.map(&:first_name)}"
    puts "custom_search.map(&:last_name): #{custom_search.map(&:last_name)}"
  end

  private

  def custom_search
   Account.index_search(query: params[:query])
  end
end
```

### The Complication

Nonetheless, in the browser, it doesn't seem to be working. With the above code, searching via the browser, I can't reproduce the success.

When I search for `"bob "`, the output in my server console is

```
params[:query]: bob
custom_search.map(&:first_name): ["Bob"]
custom_search.map(&:last_name): ["McTesterdorff"]
```

but as soon as I search for `"bob m"`, `"bob mct"`, or `"bob mctesterdorff"`, I get empty results (respecitvely):

```
params[:query]: bob m
custom_search.map(&:first_name): []
custom_search.map(&:last_name): []

params[:query]: bob mct
custom_search.map(&:first_name): []
custom_search.map(&:last_name): []

params[:query]: bob mctesterdorff
custom_search.map(&:first_name): []
custom_search.map(&:last_name): []
```

Do you all have any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `Account.reindex` once in a while to index/reindex new items. Or you could also add  `Account.reindex` to the according Model within an after_commit callback. This way your new data will be indexed after each insert/commit.